# Ошибка в образовании формы слова

Tags: морфология

Укажите пример с ошибкой в образовании формы слова

- к двумстам двадцати двум страницам,
- пара чулок,
- полученные паспорта,
- самый умнейший.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Самый умнейший*. Так нельзя говорить - надо или самый умный, или просто умнейший.

Answer (score 0):

самый умнейший - нарушение грамматических форм превосходной степени прилагательного. Умнейший - самый умный, умнее всех.Смешивать нельзя.